# prevent yeoman.io from minifying images

Tags: yeoman

So I've been using yeoman.io for my projects and I have a set folder structure for my images. But when I build it changes the file name of my files.

I even use:

```
$ yeoman build:text
```

because I want to only minify my css,js and html templates, yet it still minifies the images.
Not sure if im doing something wrong.

EDIT:

I commented out all instances of img in the gruntfile and that seemed to work, but I dont think thats the right way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You mean image optimization or revisioning? There is no problem to configure GruntFile.js to your own needs. It makes Yeoman/Grunt very powerful, because it is highly adaptable.

If you don't want image optimization, remove the configuration in the `img` task.

```
// Optimizes JPGs and PNGs (with jpegtran & optipng)
   img: {
   },
```

If you dont want the renaming of image files, remove the `img` line from the `rev` task:

```
// renames JS/CSS to prepend a hash of their contents for easier
// versioning
rev: {
  js: 'scripts/**/*.js',
  css: 'styles/**/*.css'
},
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have been trying to disable that `rev` task without understanding is it a part of the optimization or something else. What exactly is the use of it?

Comment: @AhmadAlfy: it's a cache buster. When you want to update your website, you need to make sure the browser is not using an old version of a resource (html, js, image, ...). The best way to make sure of this, is to add a random hash to the resource file, so it is always unique.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the image revving it will bust your cache, you should try to keep the revving and update your JS files instead.

Try updating your `usemin` block to something like this:

```
usemin: {
    html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
    css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
    js: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
    options: {
        assetsDirs: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles'
        ],
        patterns: {
            js: [
                [/(images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You should already have the `usemin` method, just add the `js` attribute with you js path regex and add the `pattern` attribute.
This will replace all occurrences of the image in your JS files with the new revved version, so that the clients' browsers don't use a cached image instead of a new one.